# Kafka connect with EventStoreDB

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I'm working on a small academic project - Event sourcing with EventStoreDB and Apache Kafka as a broker. The idea is that get events from EventStoreDB and push them to Kafka for further distribution. I saw Apache Kafka has connections to different DB systems but didn't find any connector with EvenStoreDB.
How can I create(code or use existing one) Kafka connector to EventStoreDB, so these two systems would be able to transfer events vise-versa, from Kafka to EventStoreDB and from EventStoreDB to Kafka?

Comment: I expect so, but you need to post a specific question.

Comment: More specific question: How to create(code) Kafka connector to EventStoreDB? Or at least where to start working in this direction. I saw Apache Kafka has connections to different DB systems but didn't find any connector with EvenStoreDB.

Comment: Depending on the specifics of what you need and whether .NET and F# work for you, [Propulsion](https://github.com/jet/propulsion) has components for publishing and consuming from Kafka interoperating with ESDB. Feel free to provide more context and ask questions in the [DDD-CQRS-ES #equinox or #eventstore forum](https://github.com/ddd-cqrs-es/slack-community)

Answer (score 4):

There is no official Kafka Connect Connector between Kafka and EventStoreDB, and I haven't heard about any unofficial so far. Still, there is a tool called Replicator that enables replicating data from EventStoreDB to Kafka (https://replicator.eventstore.org/docs/features/sinks/kafka/). It's open-sourced, so you can either use it or check the implementation.

For the EventStoreDB to Kafka, I recommend using the subscriptions mechanism: catch-up if you need an ordering guarantee, persistent if ordering is not critical: https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/grpc/subscriptions.html. The crucial part here is to define how to map EventStoreDB streams to Kafka topics and partitions. Typically you'd expect to have at least an ordering guarantee on the stream level, so single stream events should land to the same partition.

For Kafka to EventStoreDB integration, you could either write your own pass-through service or try to use the HTTP sink connector (e.g. https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-http/current/overview.html). EventStoreDB exposes HTTP API (https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/http-api/v5/introduction/). Sidenote, this API (Atom pub based) may be replaced with another HTTP API in the future, so the structure may change.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I know where to start and where to move in the project.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event Store Replicator, which has a [Kafka sink](https://replicator.eventstore.org/docs/features/sinks/kafka/).

Keep in mind that it doesn't do anything with regards to events schema, so things like Kafka Streams and KSQL might not work properly.

The sink was created solely for the purpose of pushing events to Kafka being used as a message broker.